# HTML5 audio on IOS: how can currentTime be less than initial value?

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, html5-audio

I have to play a **short** fragment of bigger audio. I use `currentTime` to set starting point in time, and `timeupdate` event to stop audio when required.

I noticed that on few early `timeupdate` events sometimes `currentTime` is **less** than its initial value, despite there is (obviously) no "rewind" actions.

Here is code example:

```
var start = 1;
var end = 1.3;
var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function () {
   console.log(audio.currentTime);
   if (audio.currentTime < start || audio.currentTime > end) {
      audio.pause();
   }
});
audio.currentTime = start;
audio.play();
```

For example, output of console log can be this:

```
1
0.85
0.85
1
1.02
...
```

Here's [an example](https://jsfiddle.net/threisdd/tz0cys2a/1/).

Tested on iPad with iOS 11.4.1. This problem appears only on very short time ranges ~0.3sec.

Comment: if you are satisfied with my answer, please mark it as accepted on the left side from my answer.

Answer (score -1):

At first you have a wrong question because you want that your script works on iOS. And because of this your question in title is irrelevant. We have a lot of bugs on iOS and the iOS developers do not want to correct them. It is a bug. Write to support from iOS and ask there "How is it possible?".

At second you have two questions in your post because your script does not work on iOS like you it want.

I wrote for you the solution. Make sure you are not trying to call the audio before the audio element has metadata loaded (first mistake). Then you have the second mistake: instead of:

```
if(audio.currentTime < start || audio.currentTime > end) //your mistake
```

you have to write:

```
if(audio.currentTime >= end)
```

**The solution (it works on iOS too)**

```js
var start = 1,
    end = 1.3,
    audio = document.getElementById('audio'),
    button = document.getElementById('button'),
    log = document.getElementById('log');


audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function()
{
   writeLog(audio.currentTime);

   //your mistake: if(audio.currentTime < start || audio.currentTime > end)
   if(audio.currentTime >= end)
   {
      audio.pause();
   }
});

function writeLog(value)
{
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = value;
    log.insertBefore(div, log.firstChild);
}

audio.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function()
{
    audio.pause();
    button.removeAttribute('disabled');
});

button.addEventListener('click', function()
{
    log.insertBefore(log.lastChild.cloneNode(!0), log.firstChild);
    audio.currentTime = start;
    audio.play();
});
```

```css
#log
{
    width:100%;
    height:18em;
    overflow-y:auto;
    font:3em 'Courier New';
    background:#069;
    color:#7e0
}
#log div:last-child{display:none}
```

```html
<!--
For this link from your example (on jsfiddle.net) is only a download is possible, but not using as source:
http://techslides.com/demos/samples/sample.m4a
-->
<audio id="audio" preload="auto">
    <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/samples/sample.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
    <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/samples/sample.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
    <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/samples/sample.aac" type="audio/aac"/>
</audio>

<button id="button" disabled style="width:9em;height:3em;font-size:3em">Play</button>
<br><br>
<div id="log"><div><hr></div></div>
```

The snippet on SO does not work because it is in sandbox.

See this working [example on codepen.io](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PBaKqq).